# ActionCable. WebSocket is closed before the connection is established

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, actioncable

[image]

Sometimes connection cannot be established and broke UX, this bug appears not regular and only on production environment

I've tried to increase `ActionCable.ConnectionMonitor.staleThreshold`, but it leads to bug while users send messages to chat.

Any approaches to handle it?

Comment: Is the SSL cert in order? Any authentication gimmicks? Anything showing up in the logs?

Comment: I am seeing the same thing. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @Geo242 I can't found my code. But idea was something like: force reconnect if connection is absent, status of connection you can get from ActionCable object